# React - Set object properties from array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop, object

I have the following object and values:

```
const [validFilters, setValidFilters] = useState({});
const [endedEvents, setEndedEventsSort] = useState(false);
const [joinedEvents, setJoinedEventsSort] = useState(true);
const [startDate, setStartDateSort] = useState(false);
const [newest, setNewestSort] = useState(true);
```

I have the following array with objects:

```
const filterEvents = [
    {name: 'endedEvents' , value: endedEvents}, 
    {name: 'joinedEvents', value: joinedEvents}, 
    {name: 'newest', value: newest},
    {name: 'startDate', value: startDate}, 
];
```

on useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  handleFilters(filterEvents);
}, [filterEvents]);
```

I have the following function:

```
const handleFilters = data =>
{
   data.map(filter => {
     if (filter.value)
     {
       newValidFilters =
       {
         [filter.name]: [filter.value],
       }
     }
    })

  setValidFilters(newValidFilters);
}
```

My expected output:
validFilters should contain new properties which are true from filterEvents.

Also I have an infinite loop due to useEffect, I am totally exhausted and have no idea what I'm doing at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting a different property each time and re-setting your `newValidFilters` in each loop, so your object ends up having at most 1 property (if true)

```
const handleFilters = data =>
{
   data.map(filter => {
     if (filter.value)
     {
       newValidFilters =
       {
         [filter.name]: [filter.value],
       }
     }
    })

  setValidFilters(newValidFilters);
}
```

change that part

```
   newValidFilters =
   {
     [filter.name]: [filter.value],
   }
```

with this

```
   newValidFilters[filter.name] = filter.value
```

Comment: newValidFilters[filter.name] = filter.value, did the trick. [filter.value] would set the property value with an array containing the value.

I haven't slept all night while working, thanks for sharing some brainpower with me. <3

Comment: yes correct didnt notice that. i'll edit my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

**remove filterEvents from the dependency array in useEffect to avoid infinite loop.**
It's happening beacause setValidFilters changes the filterEvents and due to it's presence in dependency array, it calls useEffect every time whenever the dependency changes, which creates an infinite loop.

Comment: Asim, you're more than correct although I have to trigger handleFilters on page load and at this point I have no idea how I should treat this.

I'm thinking of setting a handler with a switch statement, and each button that sets the filters to true or false has the handler inside the onClick event listener and passes a value from which the switch statement decides which filter to set true/false and trigger handleFilters.

Comment: for a general click handler  this example can help you... `const [values, setValues] = useState({isLonger: true, isSmaller: false})`        `const onClickHandler = e => { setValues({...values, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})}`

Comment: Asim, that's not bad at all, it could shorten my code so much more, although I have 2 buttons and 2 checkboxes, which need to change value on click as well, nonetheless this put me on a good path, if you have anymore suggestions don't hesitate to reply back, thank you so much!